# Why am I getting "Type '{ items: string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & string[]'." in my React hook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component `Table<T>` that looks like this:

```
interface Props<T> {
  cells: Array<TableCell<T>>;
  headers: TableHeader[];
  items: T[];
}

export default function Table<T>({ cells, headers, items }: Props<T>) {
  ...
}
```

In order to avoid importing `Table`, `TableCell` and `TableHeader` in every file where I want to use `Table` I've made a hook `useTable` that looks like this:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

import Table from '../components/Table';
import type TableCell from '../types/TableCell';
import type TableHeader from '../types/TableHeader';

export default function useTable<T>() {
  const [tableCells, setTableCells] = useState<Array<TableCell<T>>>([]);
  const [tableHeaders, setTableHeaders] = useState<TableHeader[]>([]);

  function CurriedTable(items: T[]) {
    return (
      <Table<T>
        cells={tableCells}
        headers={tableHeaders}
        items={items}
      />
    );
  }

  return {
    setTableCells,
    setTableHeaders,
    Table: CurriedTable,
  };
}
```

But now when I call `useTable<string>()` and attempt to use the `Table` component returned from my hook I get the following error:

```
Type '{ items: string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & string[]'.
  Property 'items' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & string[]'.
```

Hovering the returned `Table` component tells me it expects a prop `items` of type `string[]`.[image: A hovered Table variable with the typing "const Table: (items: string[]) => JSX.Element]

The prop I'm passing into the returned `Table` component is indeed of type `string[]`.[image: A hovered variable of type string[]]

Trying to use the returned `Table` component with no props at all yields the following error:

```
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'string[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.
```

This also seems nonsensical to me. I would like to understand better what is going wrong here.

Comment: Components take a plain *object* as props. You forgot to destructure: `function CurriedTable({ items }: { items: T[] }) {`

Comment: @vr. Gah, I knew it would be something very dumb that I overlooked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: I forgot to destructure the props I was passing to `CurriedTable`. It should instead be:

```
  function CurriedTable({ items }: { items: T[] }) {
    ...
  }
```

Credit to user vr.